# Querying and linking to from join tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

Two Questions:

1) I have a retreats/:id view where I can display the team names that are affixed to a specific retreat. I can view the team names with the following query in the view:

```
<p>Teams: <%= @retreat.teams.pluck(:name).to_sentence %></p>
```

However, instead of just displaying the name, how would I both display the name of the team and link to the team team/:id

2) In this retreats/:id view, I would also like to display the users that are part of a team, but I am really stuck trying to go through sql joins, etc.

models

**retreat.rb**

```
class Retreat < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  delegate :name, to: :user, prefix: true
  belongs_to :account

  validates :name, presence: true

  has_many :retreat_teams
  has_many :teams, through: :retreat_teams
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :retreat_teams
end
```

**team.rb**

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account

  has_many :team_members
  has_many :users, through: :team_members
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :team_members

  has_many :retreats
  has_many :retreats, through: :retreat_teams
end
```

**team_members.rb**

```
class TeamMember < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First part can be done this way

```
<% retreat.teams.each do |team| %>
  <%= link_to(team.name, team_path(team.id)) %>  # or whatever the path helper is
<% end %>
```

Second part, you can run this query instead

```
@teams = Team.where(retreat_id: @retreat.id).includes(:users)
```

Then in UI you can show like this

```
<% @teams.each do |team| %>
  Team: <%= link_to(team.name, team_path(team.id)) %>  # or whatever the path helper is
  Team Users: <%= team.users.pluck(:name).to_sentence %>
<% end %>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: would you happen to know how to put the second part in a view format?

Comment: Thank you. Put me on the right track. I am using the name of person gem, so :name generally works. But in this case I needed to use the following: `<%= team.users.pluck(:first_name, :last_name).map { |names| names.join(" ") }.to_sentence %>`

Comment: @BryanBeshore great, can you accept the answer if it helped answer your questions?

Answer (score 1):

> 1) I have a retreats/:id view where I can display the team names that
>   are affixed to a specific retreat. ...However, instead of just
>   displaying the name, how would I both display the name of the team and
>   link to the team team/:id

Don't use `.pluck` unless you actually want just a single column as an array or the raw data from several columns without instantiating model instances. `.pluck` is both overused and misused. It makes zero sense to pluck something if you then need to fetch the rest of the columns later anyways.

Instead just iterate though the model instances:

```
<% @resort.teams.each do |team| %>
  <%= link_to team.name, team %>
<% end %>
```

If you have declared the route with `resources :teams`. Rails will figure out the route all by itself - that's the power of convention over configuration.

> 2) In this retreats/:id view, I would also like to display the users
>   that are part of a team, but I am really stuck trying to go through
>   sql joins, etc.

You don't really have to do any work joining. Just eager_load the association to avoid n+1 queries:

```
def show 
  @resort = Resort.eager_load(teams: :users).find(params[:id])
end
```

```
<% @resort.teams.each do |team| %>
  <div class="team">
    <h3><%= link_to team.name, team %></h3>
    <h4>Members:</h4>
    <% if team.users.any? %>
    <ul>
      <%= team.users.each do |user| %>
      <li><%= link_to user.name, user %></li>
      <% end %>
    <ul>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

### Another note about naming

The name TeamMember is unfortunate as it implies that its the actual person that's a member and not just a join model.

Membership or Position are better name choices.

```
class Team 
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :members, through: :memberships
end

class Membership
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :member, class_name: 'User'
end

class User
  has_many :memberships, foreign_key: :member_id
  has_many :teams, through: :memberships  
end
```

This will let you iterate through `team.members` and actually get the users instead of some join model. The above example would read after refactoring:

```
def show 
  @resort = Resort.eager_load(teams: :members).find(params[:id])
end
```

```
<% @resort.teams.each do |team| %>
  <div class="team">
    <h3><%= link_to team.name, team %></h3>
    <h4>Members:</h4>
    <% if team.members.any? %>
    <ul>
      <%= team.members.each do |member| %>
      <li><%= link_to member.name, member %></li>
      <% end %>
    <ul>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```